# How to retrieve of index of for-loop rendered React Components

Tags: reactjs

I have a provider that will return a list of elements I need to render. Each item in this list must also have a button adjacent to it that will perform some action based on the selected element. I am rendering this view like so:

```
render(){
  <div name="enclosing div">
    {this._renderList()}
  </div>
}

_renderList(){
  var result = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (i; i < this.mylist.length; ++i) {
    result.push(<p> {this.myList[i]} </p>);
    result.push(<Button onClick={ () => this.clicked(params) } />);
  }
  return result;
}
```

In my click handler, I require the information that was in the < p > tags. I thought that this approach would work:

```
<Button onClick ={() => this.clicked(i)} />
```

But when I do this, **i** always = mylist.length at the time of clicking.

So next, I thought of having my Button hold a key property like so:

```
<Button index={i} onClick = {...} />
```

But I realized I have no idea how to pass i from index to onClick. How can I do this?

Am I approaching this list-rendering wrong to begin with?

Comment: key is quite a special property in react as they use it for when you're trying to display an array of components, and I'm unsure if you can access it using props or if you have to go through a roundabout way. I'd probably use something else like `index` and just ask for `this.props.index` in the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this also:

```
render(){
  <div name="enclosing div">
    {this._renderList()}
  </div>
}

_renderList(){
  var result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.mylist.length; i++) {
    result.push(<p> {this.myList[i]} </p>);
    result.push(<Button onClick={this.clicked.bind(this,params)} />);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Similarly you can bind n numbers of values with `onClick` event.

Your case should also work, Check this example:

```js
class App extends React.Component{

   onClick(index){
      console.log('index', index);
   }
   
   renderlist(){
       let list = [], a=[1,2,3,4];
       for(let i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
           list.push(<p>Item: {i}</p>)
           list.push(<button onClick={()=>this.onClick(i)}>Click Me</button>)
       }
       return list;
   }
   
   render(){
      return(
          <div>
             {
               this.renderlist()
             }
          </div>
      )
   }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't realize until trying your code snippet to realize that initializing my for-loop counter outside the for loop was the source of my troubles.